# WorksheetFunction.Match miss match

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I don't get the same result for those two lignes. Can someone explain me?

```
    Dim mnt As String
    Dim I As Integer

Ligne = 3

'Case 1: Working
mnt = Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(r.Offset(, -4), Sheets(7).Range("I3:I200"), 0) + 2, 9).Address
    
'Case 2: Not working
mnt = Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(r.Offset(, -4), Sheets(7).Range("I" & Ligne & ":I200"), 0) + 2, 9).Address
```

But if I do `Range("I" & Ligne & ":I200").select` it select correctly the range I3:I200

In the case 2, there's no error message, it juste seams to always return the value of I3 instead of searching in I3:I200.

Can someone explain me why it doesn't work in the second case?

thank you

Comment: This seems like an X Y problem. You're trying to do X, with a flawed idea Y, but you're asking how to solve a problem in Y when you should be asking about X. Doing `Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(` is an extremely sub-optimal way of navigating a sheet. Tell me what are you trying to accomplish and I'll work with you to find an optimal strategy.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The two invoked code lines are equivalent. It is not the most appropriate way (without placing the match result in a `Variant` variable and catch an eventual error), but working on similar range it should work in the same way. Anyhow, please, use `Application` instead of `WorksheetFunction`. If you place the `match` return in a `Variant` variable, it will not raise an error.

Comment: @Toddleson 

Simply said, I'm trying to do a Vlookup (search a string in an area) and return the cell's adress instead of the value. The goal is to write something in the cell next to found value.

It works well with the first line of code. What I'm trying to add in the second line is a minimum row. So instead of searching in row 1:200 it will search in row I:200 where I the the last row were I found a value. Since my data is chrnological, I don't want to get results previous to the last data found.

Comment: @Toddleson
The full macro: I'm doing a conciliation. I have serval account sheets and one master sheets (sheet 7) all in the same workbook. For each row in the master sheet, I want to know it correpond to witch row from witch account sheets. My idea was to search day per day in each sheets for a row with the same date and amount. (not sure how I'll do that to be honest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comments, I would suggest switching methods to use [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) and [.FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext). These two methods can quickly search a sheet for a string value and return its position. The FindNext method allows you to repeat the search, finding other cells with the same string value.

Here is a simple example of how to make a `.Find` and `.FindNext` loop.

```vb
Sub Example()
    'Find all instances of "Steve" on the activesheet and highlight them
    Call Highlight("Steve")
End Sub

Sub Highlight(FindText As String, Optional WithinSheet As Worksheet)
    If WithinSheet Is Nothing Then Set WithinSheet = ActiveSheet

    Dim rFirst As Range
    Set rFirst = WithinSheet.Cells.Find(What:=FindText, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    
    Dim rNext As Range
    Set rNext = rFirst
    Do
        Set rNext = WithinSheet.Cells.FindNext(After:=rNext)
        rNext.Interior.Color = 65535
    Loop While Not rNext.Address = rFirst.Address
End Sub
```

To create your own sub using this idea, you can replace the line `rNext.Interior.Color = 65535` with any other things you would like done to each cell found during this loop. For example you could do `rNext.Offset(0,1) = "Here!"` to insert some text beside each found cell.